# Check if a string in a Pandas DataFrame column is in a list of strings

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

If I have a frame like this

```py
frame = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": ["the cat is blue", "the sky is green", "the dog is black"]
})
```

and I want to check if any of those rows contain a certain word I just have to do this.

```py
frame["b"] = (
   frame.a.str.contains("dog") |
   frame.a.str.contains("cat") |
   frame.a.str.contains("fish")
)
```

`frame["b"]` outputs:

```
0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: b, dtype: bool
```

If I decide to make a list:

```py
mylist = ["dog", "cat", "fish"]
```

How would I check that the rows contain a certain word in the list?

Comment: The method in the accepted answer will find, for example, substring 'the' in a word 'there'. For a method finding **exact** words see here: [Creating a new column by finding exact word in a column of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49769706/creating-a-new-column-by-finding-exact-word-in-a-column-of-strings)

Answer (score 139, accepted):

```
frame = pd.DataFrame({'a' : ['the cat is blue', 'the sky is green', 'the dog is black']})

frame
                  a
0   the cat is blue
1  the sky is green
2  the dog is black
```

The [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) method accepts a regular expression pattern:

```
mylist = ['dog', 'cat', 'fish']
pattern = '|'.join(mylist)

pattern
'dog|cat|fish'

frame.a.str.contains(pattern)
0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

Because regex patterns are supported, you can also embed flags:

```
frame = pd.DataFrame({'a' : ['Cat Mr. Nibbles is blue', 'the sky is green', 'the dog is black']})

frame
                     a
0  Cat Mr. Nibbles is blue
1         the sky is green
2         the dog is black

pattern = '|'.join([f'(?i){animal}' for animal in mylist])  # python 3.6+

pattern
'(?i)dog|(?i)cat|(?i)fish'
 
frame.a.str.contains(pattern)
0     True  # Because of the (?i) flag, 'Cat' is also matched to 'cat'
1    False
2     True
```

Comment: This significantly speeds up what I was doing. Is there any way to return the sub pattern (say, *dog*) matched instead of True False?

Comment: Figured it out: to return the matched pattern use `frame.a.str.extract(pattern)`

Comment: @Andy Hayden How to print pattern values in case output is True

Comment: @Andy Hayden not it doesn't work tried it gives value error. Can you suggest something else.

Comment: I mean the expected output should be True Cat etc.., in place of True alone

Comment: @Yog you can set it as a column: `frame["contains"] = frame.a.str.contains(pattern)`

Comment: @Yog , Did you find a solution to your question about how to get the matching item ?

Comment: @AndyHayden this throws me this error `error: multiple repeat at position 86`. any reason why? I am looking from 500 list of strings.

Answer (score 57):

For list should work

```py
print(frame[frame["a"].isin(mylist)])
```

See [`pandas.DataFrame.isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html).

Comment: Will this work even if you're looking for potentially a substring from a list? That is, if you want to match any substring of column 'a' to any element in mylist, will this catch it?

Comment: No it does not work for substrings. It only matches the entire string and is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 9):

After going through the comments of the accepted answer of extracting the string, this approach can also be tried.

```
frame = pd.DataFrame({'a' : ['the cat is blue', 'the sky is green', 'the dog is black']})

frame
              a
0   the cat is blue
1  the sky is green
2  the dog is black
```

Let us create our list which will have strings that needs to be matched and extracted.

```
mylist = ['dog', 'cat', 'fish']
pattern = '|'.join(mylist)
```

Now let create a function which will be responsible to find and extract the substring.

```
import re
def pattern_searcher(search_str:str, search_list:str):

    search_obj = re.search(search_list, search_str)
    if search_obj :
        return_str = search_str[search_obj.start(): search_obj.end()]
    else:
        return_str = 'NA'
    return return_str
```

We will use this function with pandas.DataFrame.apply

```
frame['matched_str'] = frame['a'].apply(lambda x: pattern_searcher(search_str=x, search_list=pattern))
```

Result :

```
              a             matched_str
   0   the cat is blue         cat
   1  the sky is green         NA
   2  the dog is black         dog
```

Comment: `pattern_searcher()` will also return those characters in the string. for example, `catastrophe` will also return `cat`. `hotdog` will return `dog`

Comment: Moreover, if `mylist = ['dog', 'cat', 'fish', dogs]`, the function will identify by order. for example, `dogs are cool` will return `dog` instead of `dogs`.

Answer (score 0):

We can check for three patterns simultaneously using pipe, for example

```
for i in range(len(df)):
       if re.findall(r'car|oxide|gen', df.iat[i,1]):
           df.iat[i,2]='Yes'
       else:
           df.iat[i,2]='No'
```