# How can I replace a column given a specific condition in python?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe that contains multiple columns as below...

```
Chr1    Cufflinks   exon    28354206    28354551    .   .   .   gene_id "XLOC_008369"; transcript_id "TCONS_00014347"; exon_number "1"; oId "CUFF.2405.1"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS10073";
Chr1    Cufflinks   exon    28785549    28786194    .   .   .   gene_id "XLOC_008370"; transcript_id "TCONS_00014348"; exon_number "1"; oId "CUFF.2441.1"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS10074";
Chr1    Cufflinks   exon    29328712    29329210    .   .   .   gene_id "XLOC_008371"; transcript_id "TCONS_00014349"; exon_number "1"; oId "CUFF.2495.1"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS10075";
Chr1    Cufflinks   exon    29427951    29428406    .   .   .   gene_id "XLOC_008372"; transcript_id "TCONS_00014350"; exon_number "1"; oId "CUFF.2506.1"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS10076";
Chr1    Cufflinks   exon    29460116    29460585    .   .   .   gene_id "XLOC_008373"; transcript_id "TCONS_00014351"; exon_number "1"; oId "CUFF.2509.1"; class_code "u"; tss_id "TSS10077";
```

What i am trying to do is, if any of the items in my list is present in one of the column of the dataframe, then i replace the 2nd column from `Cufflinks` to `lincRNA`.

One problem is the column that i am using for making the key in the dictionary has multiple rows in the dataframe and because of that i am getting only unique key and so the total number of rows that are outputted are not the same as the input.

Here is my code so far...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

file_in = open("lincRNA_final_transcripts.fa")
file_in2 = open("AthalianaslutteandluiN30merged.gtf")
file_out = open("updated.gtf", 'w')

sites = []
result = {}

for line in file_in:
    line = line.strip()
    if line.startswith(">"):
        line = line[1:]
        gene = str.split(line, ".")
        gene = gene[0]
        sites.append(gene)


for line2 in file_in2:
    line2 = line2.strip().split()
    line3 = str.split(line2[11], ";")
    line3 = line3[0]
    line3 = line3[1:-1]
    result[line3] = line2


for id in sites:
    id2 = str(id)
    if id2 in result.keys():
        result[id][1] = "lincRNA"

for val in result.values():
    file_out.write("\t".join(val))
    file_out.write("\n")
```

Comment: Could you explain what is a df?

Comment: Unless an acronym is widely used (i.e. it should be at least listed on the Wikipedia disambiguation page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DF), then it will be essentially meaningless to those who may be able to answer your question.

Comment: Sorry it is a dataframe or a text file with multiple columns

Comment: I have now edited my question

Comment: Why would you re-invent the wheel? There are perfectly sound libraries for data/dataframe manipulation in Python, like [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to give a walkthrough of how you would do this in [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html). Pandas is a python library for handling dataframes and learning it makes it easy to do dataframe manipulations.

1. Install pandas

   ```
   sudo pip install pandas
   ```
2. Load your data into a pandas dataframe object. It seems gtf is a tab delimited file, so pass `\t` as the separator. If there is no header line pass `None`, if the first line is a header then pass 0 instead. For more information on the parameters, see [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#csv-text-files).

   ```
   import pandas
   df = pd.read_csv('AthalianaslutteandluiN30merged.gtf', sep = '\t', header = None, engine = 'python')

       0      1             2       3       4     5 6 7            8  
   0   Chr1    Cufflinks   exon 28354206 28354551 . . .    gene_id "XLOC_008369"   transcript_id "TCONS_00014347"  exon_number "1" oId "CUFF.2405.1"   class_code "u"  tss_id "TSS10073"
   1   Chr1    Cufflinks   exon 28785549 28786194 . . .    gene_id "XLOC_008370"   transcript_id "TCONS_00014348"  exon_number "1" oId "CUFF.2441.1"   class_code "u"  tss_id "TSS10074"
   ```
3. Check if the strings in column 8 contain a substring that is also contained in your `sites` list. We will use [this idea.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972938/check-if-string-in-pandas-dataframe-column-is-in-list)

   ```
   sites = ["XLOC_008369", "XLOC_008369"]
   pattern = '|'.join(sites)
   mask = df[8].str.contains(pattern)
   ```
4. Use boolean indexing to change `Cufflinks` to `lincRNA` if column 8 contains a substring that matches with an element in `sites` list. See [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing), for more on pandas indexing.

   ```
   df.loc[mask,1] = 'lincRNA'
   ```

EDIT: Use `str.contains` to check if a pandas column contains an element in the list.

Comment: This is awesome. When i read the gtf file, i'm getting this error "ValueError: Expected 18 fields in line 48, saw 19". What do you think i'm doing wrong?

Comment: @upendra Pandas expects every row to have the same number columns in this case it expects 18. However, it appears that in line 48, there are 19 columns. It may be best to open your file and see if there is an extra tab or semicolon.

Comment: you are right, there are several rows that have extra columns. Is there a way to deal with this extra columns?

Comment: @upendra I have edited my response using another function to do the matches. You no longer have to use semicolons as a separator which will prevent additional columns from appearing.

Comment: it finally worked. Thanks a lot for all the help. Much appreciated