# pandas string contains lookup: NaN leads to Value Error

Tags: pandas

If you would like to filter those rows for which a string is in a column value, it is possible to use something like `data.sample_id.str.contains('hph')` (answered before: [check if string in pandas dataframe column is in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972938/check-if-string-in-pandas-dataframe-column-is-in-list), or [Check if string is in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30944577/check-if-string-is-in-a-pandas-dataframe)).

However, my lookup column contains emtpy cells. Terefore, `str.contains()` yields `NaN` values and I get an value error upon indexing.

```
`ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values``
```

What works:

```
# get all runs 
mask = [index for index, item in enumerate(data.sample_id.values) if 'zent' in str(item)]
```

Is there a more elegant and faster method (similar to `str.contains()`) than this one ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set parameter `na` in [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) to `False`:

```
print (df.a.str.contains('hph', na=False))
```

Using `EdChum` sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['hph', np.NaN, 'sadhphsad', 'hello']})
print (df)
           a
0        hph
1        NaN
2  sadhphsad
3      hello

print (df.a.str.contains('hph', na=False))
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you can filter those rows out also

```
data['sample'].dropna().str.contains('hph')
```

Example:

```
In [38]:
df =pd.DataFrame({'a':['hph', np.NaN, 'sadhphsad', 'hello']})
df

Out[38]:
           a
0        hph
1        NaN
2  sadhphsad
3      hello

In [39]:
df['a'].dropna().str.contains('hph')

Out[39]:
0     True
2     True
3    False
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

So by calling `dropna` first you can then safely use `str.contains` on the `Series` as there will be no `NaN` values

Another way to handle the null values would be to use `notnull`:

```
In [43]:
(df['a'].notnull()) & (df['a'].str.contains('hph'))

Out[43]:
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

but I think passing `na=False` would be cleaner (@jezrael's answer)