# Creating a new column by finding exact word in a column of strings

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a new column with 1 or 0, if any of the words in a list is matched exaclty with the dataframe string column.

```
list_provided=["mul","the"]
#how my dataframe looks
id  text
a    simultaneous there the
b    simultaneous there
c    mul why
```

**Expected output**

```
id  text                     found
a    simultaneous there the   1
b    simultaneous there       0
c    mul why                  1
```

Second row is assigned 0, since **either of** "mul" or "the" are not exactly matching in the string column "text"

**Code tried till now**

```
#For exact match I am using the below code
data["Found"]=np.where(data["text"].str.contains(r'(?:\s|^)penalidades(?:\s|$)'),1,0)
```

How can I iterate through a loop to find exact match of all the words in the provided list of words?

**Edit:**
If i use str.contains(pattern) as suggested by Georgey, all the rows for data["Found"] becomes 1

```
data=pd.DataFrame({"id":("a","b","c","d"), "text":("simultaneous there the","simultaneous there","mul why","mul")})
list_of_word=["mul","the"]
pattern = '|'.join(list_of_word)
data["Found"]=np.where(data["text"].str.contains(pattern),1,0)

Output:
id  text                     found
a    simultaneous there the   1
b    simultaneous there       1
c    mul why                  1
d    mul                      1
```

The second row in the found column should be 0 here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check if string in pandas dataframe column is in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972938/check-if-string-in-pandas-dataframe-column-is-in-list)

Comment: @Georgy list_provided has many words. Also if I use str.contains(), even the second row will be flagged as 1
If i use data["text"].isin(list_provided) it makes all three rows zero, since it is only finding cell with only those words

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with `pd.Series.apply` and `sum` with a generator expression:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                   'text': ['simultaneous there the', 'simultaneous there', 'mul why']})

test_set = {'mul', 'the'}

df['found'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: sum(i in test_set for i in x.split()))

#   id                    text  found
# 0  a  simultaneous there the      1
# 1  b      simultaneous there      0
# 2  c                 mul why      1
```

---

The above provides a *count*. If you just need a Boolean, use `any`:

```
df['found'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x: any(i in test_set for i in x.split()))
```

For integer representation, chain `.astype(int)`.

Comment: For cases where my words in the list have spaces, how to resolve them? I have updated my post with the edit (Edit 2)

Comment: This is *much* more complex. I suggest you ask a separate question. I will roll back to your previous question here.

Comment: Sure...I will do that

Answer (score 2):

**Edit 1**

try this code

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe = [["simultaneous there the","simultaneous there","mul why","mul"],["a","b","c","d"]]
list_of_word = ["mul","the"]


dic = {
    "id": dataframe[1],
    "text": dataframe[0] 
}

DataF = pd.DataFrame(dic)

found = []
for key in DataF["text"]:
    anyvari = False
    for damn in key.split(" "):

        if(damn==list_of_word[0] or damn==list_of_word[1]):
            anyvari = True

            break
        else:
            continue
    if(anyvari!=True):
        found.append(0)
    else:
        found.append(1)


DataF["found"] = found         


print(DataF)
```

it will give you like this

```
  id                    text  found
0  a  simultaneous there the      1
1  b      simultaneous there      0
2  c                 mul why      1
3  d                     mul      1
```

Comment: Thanks @Amam. If my words in the list has spaces. For example my words in the list are "mul the". Then how to resolve this issue? I cannot use key.split then!!

Comment: you mean, if the words is "mul the" then it found 2? or what,