# Count occurences of set words that can be contained in a DataFrame column composed by a list of strings on a global and single row scale

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, counter

I am hoping I am not creating a duplicate lol, but I spend more than hours looking for something similar to my questions :)

Said that, I have the following input:

```
foo= {"Brand":["loc doc poc",
               "roc top mop",
               "loc lot not",
               "roc lot tot",
               "loc bot sot",
               "nap rat sat"] }

word_list=["loc","top","lot"]
df=pd.DataFrame(foo)
```

2 Desired Outputs

1 **Dictionary with the occurrences stored**

2 **New column containing the number of occurrences for each row**

```
#Outputs: 
counter_dic={"loc":3,"top":1,"lot":2}

            Brand   count
0   loc  doc  poc       1
1   roc  top  mop       1
2   loc  lot  not       2
3   roc  lot  tot       1
4   toc  bot  sot       1
5   nap  rat  sat       0
```

The only idea that I had:

- Count how many times a set of terms occurs. I can create a bag of words and then filtering based on the dictionary keys?

If you find a similar question, this can be closed obviously.

I checked the following ones

[This one of the most similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53350793/how-to-check-if-pandas-column-has-value-from-list-of-string)

[Check If a String Is In A Pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30944577/check-if-string-is-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

[Python Lists Finding The Number Of Times A String Occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11800755/python-lists-finding-number-of-times-a-string-occurs)

[Count Occurrences Of A Substring In A List Of Strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45738789/count-occurrences-of-a-substring-in-a-list-of-strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one potential solution using [`str.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.count.html) to create an interim count DataFrame which will help with both outputs.

```
df_counts = pd.concat([df['Brand'].str.count(x).rename(x) for x in word_list], axis=1)
```

Looks like:

```
   loc  top  lot
0    1    0    0
1    0    1    0
2    1    0    1
3    0    0    1
4    1    0    0
5    0    0    0
```

---

**1 - Dictionary with the occurrences stored**

```
df_counts.sum().to_dict()
```

[out]

```
{'loc': 3, 'top': 1, 'lot': 2}
```

---

**2 - New column containing the number of occurrences for each row**

```
df['count'] = df_counts.sum(axis=1)
```

[out]

```
         Brand  count
0  loc doc poc      1
1  roc top mop      1
2  loc lot not      2
3  roc lot tot      1
4  loc bot sot      1
5  nap rat sat      0
```

Comment: I noticed that in my list of words one of these is `+watt` and it generates and error: 
`error: nothing to repeat at position 0` I was thinking to replace this special character with `.replace("+","")` any better suggestion to deal with this kind of exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to get the count into dictionary form:

```
df['Brand'].str.split(' ').explode().to_frame('Brand').groupby('Brand').size().loc[word_list].to_dict()
```

Here is a way to get the count:

```
df['count'] = df['Brand'].str.get_dummies(sep=' ').loc[:,word_list].sum(axis=1)
```