# How do i drop columns from a dataframe based on whether the items in a list appear anywhere in a field

Tags: python, filtering

OK, I have a list of stopwords in a list and I would like to remove rows of a DataFrame where these might appear anywhere in a column that contains a string.

```
wordlist = ['hello','goodbye','you']

column1           column2 
this is me        10
how are you?      15
Goodbye Jim       20  
Hello you         25
```

What I would like to end up with is the following where the rows have been removed that contain those found in the wordlist

```
column1       column2
this is me    10
```

I am thinking should I split the `column1` and then search each column or is there a way that I can do this straight on the column?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check if string in pandas dataframe column is in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972938/check-if-string-in-pandas-dataframe-column-is-in-list)

Comment: Your expected result doesn't seem to match your stated rule...

Comment: Sorry folks I made a mistake in my example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
wordlist = ['hello','goodbye','you']


df = pd.DataFrame([["this is me", 10], ["how are you?", 15], ["Goodbye Jim", 20], ["Hello you", 25]],
                     columns=["column1", "column2"])

Output:
column1           column2 
this is me        10
how are you?      15
Goodbye Jim       20  
Hello you         25

df = df.loc[~(df['column1'].str.contains('|'.join(wordlist), case=False))]

Output:
column1       column2
this is me    10
```

Comment: When I run this I get the error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'str'`