# Pandas trying to find a solution to extract string better with different pattern

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a column that looks like this:

```
  Period 
0 summer 2020
1 winter 2021
2 day 
3 March '20
4 June '21
5 12-13 April '20
6 summer 2021
7 12/03/20 base
8 week 8 '20
9 Weekend base
10 Monday base
11 BOM base
12 Year 2021
```

I want to return a new column to derive a new category. So if column Period contains the string 'summer' return 'season' or if string contains 'March' then return 'month'.

However I have a problem where some strings contain a month name preceded by a date for example 12-14 April '20. For these that have both a date and month I want to return 'weekend'.

I want this output:

```
  Period          Time
0 summer 2020     season
1 winter 2021     season
2 day             day
3 March '20       month
4 Q1 '21          quarter
5 12-14 April '20 week/weekend
6 summer 2021     season
7 12/03/20 base   day
8 week 8 '20      week/weekend
9 Weekend base    week/weekend
10 Monday base      day
11 BOM base       day
12 Year 2021      year
```

Here my attempt where I used '-' as the common character for this type of string but it doesn't solve the problem as it will return 'month' because of April in the example above.

```
df['Time'] =      pd.np.where(df.Period.str.contains("Summer"), "season",
                          pd.np.where(df.Period.str.contains("Winter"), "season",
                          pd.np.where(df.Period.str.contains("January"), "month",
                          pd.np.where(df.Period.str.contains("February"), "month",
                          pd.np.where(df.Period.str.contains("March"), "month", 
                          pd.np.where(df.Period.str.contains("April"), "month", 
                          pd.np.where(df.Period.str.contains("June"), "month", 
                          pd.np.where(df.Period.str.contains("July"), "month", 
                          pd.np.where(df.Period.str.contains("August"), "month",
                          pd.np.where(df.Period.str.contains("September"), "month",
                          pd.np.where(df.Period.str.contains("October"), "month",
                          pd.np.where(df.Period.str.contains("November"), "month", 
                          pd.np.where(df.Period.str.contains("December"), "month",
                          pd.np.where(df.Period.str.contains("Q"), "quarter",
                          pd.np.where(df.Period.str.contains("-"), "week/weekend",
                          pd.np.where(df.Period.str.contains("Week"), "week/weekend",
                          pd.np.where(df.Period.str.contains("Year"), "year", "day-ahead")))))))))))))))))
```

EDITED: added new strings to column Period (index 7-12). And changed category 'weekend' to 'week/weekend'. If it's not season, month, quarter, week/weekend, and year then I would to return 'day' like in my code at the very end.

Comment: I modified one of the answers below using my edited question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a mapping dictionary to identify all of the matches using `pd.Series.str.extract()`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Period': ['summer 2020','winter 2021','day','March \'20','Q1 \'21','12-14 April \'20','summer 2021']})

mapping = {
    'weekend': ['-'],
    'season': ['spring','summer','fall','autumn','winter'],
    'day': ['day'],
    'month': ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December'],
    'quarter': ['Q']
}

df['Time'] = pd.concat([df['Period'].str.extract('({})'.format(')|('.join(v))).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:,0] for k, v in mapping.items()], axis=1).bfill(axis=1).iloc[:,0]

invert_mapping = {i: k for k, v in mapping.items() for i in v}

df['Time'] = df['Time'].map(invert_mapping)
```

Yields:

```
            Period     Time
0      summer 2020   season
1      winter 2021   season
2              day      day
3        March '20    month
4           Q1 '21  quarter
5  12-14 April '20  weekend
6      summer 2021   season
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not much different from your solution but (hopefully) it's more readable and easier to maintain.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

seasons = "|".join(["summer", "autumn", "winter", "spring"])
months = "|".join(['January', 'February', 'March', 'April',
          'May', 'June', 'July','August', 'September',
          'October', 'November', 'December'])
quarters = "|".join([f"Q{i+1}" for i in range(4)])

x = df["Period"]

cond_list = [x.str.contains(seasons),
             x.str.contains(months),
             x.str.contains(quarters),
             x.str.contains("-"),
             x.str.contains("day")]

choice_list = ["season",
              "month",
              "quarter",
              "weekend",
              "day"]

df["Time"] = np.select(cond_list, choice_list)
```

The reason for `"|".join(...)` is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17973255/4819376)

Comment: This is not the way SO is supposed to work. If you ask a question and 2 persons take the time to offer you a working solution you can't just modify your question. Actually you could just modify one of the answers in order to achieve your goals.