# Replacing values by those in contains

Tags: python

I want to replace values in a column by those matched with `str.contains`, for example:

```
    index   data_values         
1   2.0     charizard ex       
2   3.0     poliwhirl           
3   4.0     blastoise           
5   8.0     blaine's arcanine   
6   12.0    ariados
```

My calculation:

```
poke[poke.data_values.str.contains("charizard|poliwhirl|blastoise|arcanine|ariados",na=False)]
```

Will select for those values in `str.contains`, however is there a way to replace those values that appear by the string in `contains`? This data is only an example, I'm effectively working with 100,000's of rows.

Expected output:

```
    index   data_values         
1   2.0     charizard      
2   3.0     poliwhirl           
3   4.0     blastoise           
5   8.0     arcanine    
6   12.0    ariados
```

Dictionary code to reproduce:

```
{'index': {1: 2.0, 2: 3.0, 3: 4.0, 5: 8.0, 6: 12.0},
 'data_values': {1: 'charizard ex',
  2: 'poliwhirl',
  3: 'blastoise',
  5: "blaine's arcanine",
  6: 'ariados'},
 'price2': {1: 980.88, 2: 20.0, 3: 998.98, 5: 45.0, 6: 6.3}}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a string in a Pandas DataFrame column is in a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972938/check-if-a-string-in-a-pandas-dataframe-column-is-in-a-list-of-strings)

Comment: What if, say, `data_values[1]` = `"charizard poliwhirl"`?

Comment: @ScottHunter That's a good point, we select the first word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a pattern (importing the `re` package) and then `str.extract`:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile("(charizard|poliwhirl|blastoise|arcanine|ariados)")

df["data_values"].str.extract(pattern)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
           0
1  charizard
2  poliwhirl
3  blastoise
5   arcanine
6    ariados
```