# python - pandas: creating a new dataframe with a list of keywords

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp

I have a dataframe of news headlines, like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'texto': ['El Hubble registró imágenes de una "mariposa interestelar"',
                             'Con su Audi atropelló y mató a una pareja: lo juzgan y podrían darle 25 años',
                             'Clarín cumplió 70 años y lo celebró con su personal',
                             'A diez años de Katrina, Obama visitó Nueva Orleans y celebró la recuperación',
                             'La oposición volvió a juntarse y pidió la boleta única electrónica en octubre',
                             'Hallan a casi 50 “sin papeles” muertos en un camión en Austria'],
                   'id': [1,2,3,4,5,6]})

df['texto'] = df['texto'].str.lower()

searchwords = ['hubble','audi','obama','clarín','austria']
```

And I am trying to search if each and every single of some keywords selected appear in above dataframe to create a new one. I have tried `'startswith'`, but only contains the sentences where the keyowrds are first.

```
Code:
df = df[df['texto'].str.startswith(tuple(searchwords))]

Output:

clarín cumplió 70 años y lo celebró con su per...   3
```

Do you know a way to create a pandas line or a function to create a filter like this?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a string in a Pandas DataFrame column is in a list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17972938/check-if-a-string-in-a-pandas-dataframe-column-is-in-a-list-of-strings)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
df2 = df[df['texto'].str.contains('|'.join(searchwords))]
```

Explanation:

`'|'.join(searchwords)` produces a string with the search words separated by the | (OR operator) symbol.
`df['texto'].str` provides each element of the column as a string and this is then checked to see if it contains any of the search words (hence the OR operator). This produces a series of True / False values.
The boolean series is then used to select the rows from the DataFrame df which meet the `True` condition and these form the new DataFrame df2.

Comment: Please add some explanation for your code.

Comment: There are numerous, equally valid, ways to meet this requirement. Some explanation added to my answer as requested by @user67275

Answer (score 0):

another option to do so (without vectorization hence less efficient) is:

```
def serach_term(texto, terms):
    if any([t in texto for t in terms]):
        return True
    return False
```

and

```
df['exists'] = df.apply(lambda x: serach_term(x['texto'],searchwords), axis=1)
```

desired result:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

you gain control on the function and can adjust accordingly BUT you move row by row and it's relatively slower.

```
    texto                                              id   exists
0   el hubble registró imágenes de una "mariposa i...   1   True
1   con su audi atropelló y mató a una pareja: lo ...   2   True
2   clarín cumplió 70 años y lo celebró con su per...   3   True
3   a diez años de katrina, obama visitó nueva orl...   4   True
4   la oposición volvió a juntarse y pidió la bole...   5   False
5   hallan a casi 50 “sin papeles” muertos en un c...   6   True
```